# How to tag new queues in AmazonSQS using java

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

We need to tag any queue using SQSClient in Java SDK, but earlier versions (1.11.126) do not support it and newer version are not fully supported/stable.

Comment: What do you mean by "newer version are not fully supported/stable"? Are you talking about the "version 2.0" SDK (which Amazon claims is fully supported, although might not provide all functionality) or a later version of the "1.11.x" SDK (which is also fully supported, stable, and has the operation that you want)?

Comment: We tried implementing using 1.11.476. Code compilation is done successfully. Getting below exception while execution.
com.amazonaws.client.AwsSyncClientParams.getAdvancedConfig()Lcom/amazonaws/client/builder/AdvancedConfig;: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.amazonaws.client.AwsSyncClientParams.getAdvancedConfig()Lcom/amazonaws/client/builder/AdvancedConfig;
at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.<init>(AmazonSQSClient.java:351)
at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.<init>(AmazonSQSClient.java:335)
at

Comment: This is probably caused by a mixture of dependency versions. If you're using Maven to do your builds, run `mvn dependency:tree` to see which versions you're using.

Comment: In general if you need to provide additional information in response to questions, it should go into the question, not a comment (where it's all but impossible to read). And anything code-related should be formatted as code (select it and click the `{}` button).